Xdebug - how to remove annoying inline variable content displays
When paused on a breakpoint, Xdebug is showing the content of every variable in-line on every line as shown below:

I find this highly distracting, I have the watch pane if I want to observe certain variables, or I could otherwise hover my mouse over what I want to see.
I don't like that on every line, it's showing the values automatically, it's very cluttering and confusing sometimes.
It seems to be doing this automatically on my Linux PC but not on my Windows one for some reason.
Any idea how to stop this?

Which extension(s) exactly are you using? There are multiple that could concern Xdebug
